# cannot compare arraylist values in android

Tags: android

i am creating an android application in which i want to access database from mysql for user name, phone no and email address. and i want to compare phone no from android phone contact list and the phone no getting from mysql database. for that purpose i use 2 arraylist 1st for phone contact and 2nd for mysql phone no.
my main problem is when i compare both the arraylist then i shows no result.
i attach here the code please someone help me to solve this problem.

```
public class PhoneNoActivity extends Activity{
    JSONArray jArray,jArray1;
    JSONObject jobj;
    String result = null,phone=null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;
    double lat=0;
    double lon=0;
    String user=null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        String phno=null;
        ArrayList<String> cntPhone=new ArrayList<String>();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        if(phoneNo.length()>10) {
                            phno=phoneNo.subSequence(phoneNo.length()-10, phoneNo.length()).toString();
                            // Log.e(name, phno);
                        }
                        cntPhone.add(phoneNo);
                    } 
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
        }

        ArrayList<String> cntOnline=new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            /*String phone=null;
            for(int k=0;k<=cntPhone.size();k++) {
                Log.e("k",k+"");
                phone=cntPhone.get(k);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
            */
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/ah_login_api/select.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

            String line="0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();

            Log.e("result=", result);
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                user=json_data.getString("user");
                phone=json_data.getString("phone");
                lat=json_data.getDouble("email");

                cntOnline.add(phone);
            }
            for(String s:cntOnline) {
                for(String s1:cntPhone ) {
                    if(s.equals(s1)) {
                        Log.e("match found", phone);
                    }
                }
            }
            /*
                for(int l=0;l<cntOnline.size();l++) {
                    Log.e("loop start", ""+l);
                    for(int k=0;k<cntPhone.size();k++) {
                        if(cntPhone.get(k).trim().equals(cntOnline.get(l).trim())) {
                            Log.e("match found", phone);
                        }
                    }      
                }*/
        //}
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Exception  in ",ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my php code from which i access details

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("MyContact");
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from newuser");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        $output[]=$row;
    print(json_encode($output));
    mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: how are you getting past the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Comment: with this:    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
                new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

Comment: **1.** Post an example of the JSON you get returned.
**2.** Remove all unnecessary code, like uncommented code.
**3.** Only show the part of the code, that you want us to look at.
**4.** Use a few printstatements, to see what is actually really returned from the `ContentResolver` and what is actually returned from the `JSON Array`. If String.equals doesn't return anything, nothing matches = something is wrong with the data you're trying to compare and it's not like you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2):

/* Retrieves phone numbers from Phone Contact List */

```
public ArrayList<String> getNumber() {
    String phoneNumber;
    ArrayList<String> contact_number = new ArrayList<String>();
    ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Cursor phones = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        phoneNumber = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        System.out.println(".................." + phoneNumber);
        contact_number.add(phoneNumber);
    }
    phones.close();
    return contact_number;
}
```

/* Gets the Numbers from MySQL database using object "Contact" and Compares it with the method "getNumber()" which retrieves phone numbers from Phone Contact List */

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Contact convertContact(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    String name = obj.getString("user_name");
    String mobile_no = obj.getString("mobile_no");

    boolean isMatched = false;
    contact_number = getNumber();
    for (int i = 0; i < contact_number.size(); i++) {
        if (mobile_no.equals(contact_number.get(i))) {
            isMatched = true;
            contact.setName(name);
            contact.setMobileNo(mobile_no);

        }
    }
    return isMatched ? contact : null;

}
```

/* If the number from database matches with the phone contact list add and generate in listview */

```
private class AsyncTasak extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Contact>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Contact> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        arrayadapter.setItemList(result);
        arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Contact> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList<Contact> result = new ArrayList<Contact>();

        try {
            URL u = new URL(params[0]);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            while (is.read(b) != -1)
                baos.write(b);

            String JSONResp = new String(baos.toByteArray());

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSONResp);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                Contact temp = convertContact(arr.getJSONObject(i));
                if (temp != null) {
                    result.add(temp);
                }
            }

            return result;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @Ramesh_D: I don't know but if it is, it's lacking a lot of explanation about what it's doing and why. Some context and information would enhance it a lot.